# .map second argument is current value instead of index

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I am using .map method and I am getting the second argument as the current value instead of the index so basically its upside down

I consoled log the currentValue and it shows currentValue, I consoled log "i" and it prints undefined

```
const Card = props => {
  return Array.from({length: 9}).map((i, currentValue) => {
    console.log(currentValue);
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Image
          style={{flex: 8, width: hp('50%'), height: wp('50%')}}
          source={{uri: `${props.source[currentValue]}`}}
        />
        <Text style={{flex: 2, backgroundColor: 'red', margin: 10}}>
          {props.title[1] ? `${props.title[currentValue]}` : 'Loading'}
        </Text>
        <Text style={{flex: 2, backgroundColor: 'blue', margin: 10}}>
          {props.rating[currentValue]}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: The first value of the map callback is the looped item value. Because you are using `Array.from` with no init callback, `i` will always be `void 0` (or undefined, really), while `currentValue` will be 0 to 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const data = Array.from({length: 9});
console.log(data); // [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]

data.map((val, index) => {
  console.log(val, index); // val is undefined, index is the array index (0 to 8)
})
```

Because `Array.from({length: 9})` gives you an array of 9 `undefined` so when you use a map over the array, it will print `undefined` as value, and 0-8 as index.

Answer (score 0):

[Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Parameters) takes a `currentVal` argument as the **first** and optionally, and `index` as the second.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the output.
You are creating a new array of 9 elements. The elements' value is initially `undefined`, so when you use `map` over them and `console.log` the value of the first argument to `map` (in your case i), they **will be** `undefined.`

And the second argument to `map`, in your case `currentValue`, is actually the index of the current value.

So, how you name your variables in your code is very confusing. Change them and everything looks normal:

```js
 const az = Array.from({length: 9}).map((currentValue, i) => {
  console.log(i)
  console.log(currentValue)
    })
```

And one more thing, the first argument to the `map` function isn't actually the current value but the current **element** of the array that you are performing `map` on. The element could be another array, or an object. So, better to call it `currentElement`, or something similar, that denotes that this is an element of the array and could be of any type.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for  alternate solution then try this. Otherwise above explanations are good enough :)

```
Array.from(Array(9).keys()).map(callback)
```